# Cannot run my web application on tomcat server in Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, web-applications

I just want to run the hello world web page on my tomcat server. But nothing happens. I want to troubleshoot this problem, but I don't know where to start.

I don't know what information you guys need to help me, so please request any information, I will provide them.
[image][image]
[image: The Error]

[image: Tomcat Server]

[image: I set Catalina Home]

[image: I set this too]

[image: My Tomcat Installs]

Comment: [1] You are running NetBeans 16 with JDK 8. That is an unsupported combination. From [the Release Notes for NetBeans 16](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb16/): _"The Apache **NetBeans 16 binary releases require JDK 11+**, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17"._ So upgrade your JDK (preferably to JDK 17), and then update your question if you still have problems. [2] Also, one thing to do when you have problems like this to help isolate the issue is to go to `http://localhost:8080` after you have started Tomcat to verify that Tomcat is running OK.

Comment: After starting the tomcat server, I went to `http://localhost:8080` and was able to confirm that the server is running. But when I want to stop the tomcat server, it tells me that it was unable to stop the tomcat server.

Now I'm in the process of downloading JDK 17, I will update this comment after its done.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/wcpjovc) This is what I get when I want to stop the tomcat server.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/StSlDnP) This is my error.

Comment: All your problems are irrelevant until you upgrade your JDK so that NetBeans 16 is running on a valid platform. Get rid of JDK 1.8, and do not waste time attempting anything else until you are running NetBeans with a valid JDK (i.e. JDK 11 or greater).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an install of jdk 11 with tomcat 10 and netbeans 16, after reading the documentation and reading the comments here made me understand that it was a incompatible version error.

I worked perfectly after that.